# Is there a way to remove spaces from a text file? (or prevent it in the first place)

Tags: batch-file

sidenote - not the best coder

I'm making a batch-file script, and need to read from `runfig.conf`

I've tried to use `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` but that doesn't seem to fix it. Other googling produced no results

This saves the variables to a file

```
echo %fname% > runfig.conf && echo Saving "%fname%" to file...
echo %name% >> runfig.conf && echo Saving "%name%" to file...
echo %mem% >> runfig.conf && echo Saving "%mem%" to file...
```

This reads the file:

```
< runfig.conf (
  set /p fname=
  set /p name=
  set /p mem=
)
```

Unfortunately, instead of being this:

```
database
server
4
```

it is saved as:

```
database  
server  
4
```

Notice the two spaces at the end? Those mess up my program. So, to reiterate my question, how do I remove/prevent these?

Comment: You do realise that you're`echo`ing `%var%<space>`, _introducing a trailing space yourself_, to each line; don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @SomethingDark's current answer, this will write to the config file whilst also redirecting the notification messages to the console:

```bat
@Echo Off
(   Echo=%fname%&&Echo Saving %fname% to file...>CON
    Echo=%name%&&Echo Saving %name% to file...>CON
    Echo=%fname%&&Echo Saving %mem% to file...>CON)>"runfig.conf"
```

---

As you can see, the write method is the same as the read method, other than using STDOUT instead of STDIN:

```bat
(   Set /P "fname="
    Set /P "name="
    Set /P "mem=")<"runfig.conf"
```

---

Please also remember, if the variables are being propagated from user input via `Set /P`, that your end user can input nothing or anything, you should therefore verify that the responses meet your requirements before writing them to the config file:

```bat
Rem Undefining any existing variable named fname.
Set "fname="
Rem Requesting first name input from user.
Set /P "fname=What is your first name? "
Rem Below here you should be verifying the input meets your requirements.
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about `CON`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the space you are putting between `%fname%` and `>`. There are a few ways to resolve this issue.

The first way is to simply remove the space:

```
echo %fname%>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%fname%" to file...
echo %name%>>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%name%" to file...
echo %mem%>>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%mem%" to file...
```

However, this will produce unexpected results if any of the three variable ends with a number, so this might not be the best choice for you.

You can also move the redirection statement to the beginning of the line, again removing any space after the variable:

```
>runfig.conf echo %fname%&& echo Saving "%fname%" to file...
>>runfig.conf echo %name%&& echo Saving "%name%" to file...
>>runfig.conf echo %mem%&& echo Saving "%mem%" to file...
```

If you don't need the status displayed (and you don't, because redirection isn't going to magically fail in the middle of the script), you can put everything in a single code block:

```
(
    echo %fname%
    echo %name%
    echo %mem%
)>runfig.conf
echo Values added to file.
```

Answer (score -4):

Nevermind, I found an answer on the third page of google.
For those wondering, run `set a=%a: =%` where `a` is your variable.
Thanks, anyway!

Comment: This will remove _all_ spaces from a variable called `%a%`, but it will _not_ resolve the problem in your question.